# Appending JSON data to an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, json, call

I'm trying to:

1. Fetch JSON data using $.get
2. append that data to an HTML  element $('photos') so that images are displayed using the external JSON file instead of in-line HTML.

I'm not getting any console errors and the images aren't displaying. Any help would be EXTREMELY appreciated. Thanks a lot. I have an alert to check if the JSON is loaded, and it loads fine- just doesn't change any data.

Here is my current setup:

(JSON): photoData.json

```
{  "photos": {
"1": {
  "href": "./photos/photo1.JPG",
  "src": "photos/photo1.JPG",
},
"2": {
  "href": "./photos/photo2.JPG",
  "src": "photos/photo2.JPG",
},
"3": {
  "href": "./photos/photo3.JPG",
  "src": "photos/photo3.JPG",
},
"4": {
  "href": "./photos/photo4.JPG",
  "src": "photos/photo4.JPG",
},
"5": {
  "href": "./photos/photo5.JPG",
  "src": "photos/photo5.JPG",
}}}
```

jQuery:

```
$.get("./data/photoData.json", function(photos){
alert("Data Loaded: " + photos);
let htmlStr = "";
for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++){
    htmlStr += `<figure><a href="${photos[i].href}"><img src = "${photos[i].src}"></img></a></figure>`
}
$('Photos').html(htmlStr);});
```

Comment: You are using `photos.length` when `photos` is actually an object. Use `for..in` instead.

Comment: Is the alert statement shown?

Comment: $('Photos').html(htmlStr); is not a valid selector add . for a class or # for an id of your div

Comment: what are you getting in the alert box. Also you may want to use JSON.parse(photos) in the callback !!!

Comment: All modern browsers have support for template literals, @FaizKhan.

Comment: Yeah i just tried it. I will have to update my comment. Thanks @Andy

Comment: @jeff I'm getting the following back from the alert: Data loaded: [object Object]

Comment: @palaѕн Can you expand on your answer please? I'm desperate and don't quite understand how I'd implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`photos` is a object of objects not an array. So use `for...in` instead:

```
$.get("./data/photoData.json", function(data) {
  const photos = data.photos;
  let htmlStr = '';
  for (let photo in photos) {
    htmlStr += `<figure><a href="${photos[photo].href}"><img src="${photos[photo].src}"></img></a></figure>`
  }
});
```

And something that's been raised in the comments: `$('Photos')` is not a valid jQuery selector. I suspect that you have an element with an id called `Photos` - you just need to add the hash to the selector: `$('#Photos')`.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/f8423fxL/5/)**

Comment: I think I understand? I've adapted the code with your solution but I'm still not getting any results. Also your JSFiddle might be broken, I'm not getting results there either. Sorry if something here is going over my head...  

I also receive the following with your current solution: Identifier 'photos' has already been declared

Though I can't see anywhere in my code that I've declared it...

Comment: Open your dev console to see the results in the fiddle. In addition, remember that you're returning data that is an object that has one object called `photos`. I've updated my answer with your rest call. Perhaps you can understand a little better what's happening.

Comment: Thanks so much Andy, that definitely helped clarify where I was going wrong. Appreciate the help!